# How to make shell command process finish?

Tags: java

I want to execute a specific shell command on a Linux machine with Java.
So I found a tutorial by/from baeldung.com.

[Link to the tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java)

My problem is that even the example command (process) never finishes.

```
private static class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private Consumer<String> consumer;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream inputStream, Consumer<String> consumer) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines()
          .forEach(consumer);
    }
}

boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name")
  .toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
String homeDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
Process process;
if (isWindows) {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime()
      .exec(String.format("cmd.exe /c dir %s", homeDirectory));
} else {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime()
      .exec(String.format("sh -c ls %s", homeDirectory));
}
StreamGobbler streamGobbler = 
  new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), System.out::println);
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
assert exitCode == 0;
```

Hope that somebody has an idea.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, a background thread is started. Since the thread is not a *daemon* thread, the JVM will not terminate until the thread stops running. That never happens, so your Java program keeps running, even though the `main` thread has terminated.

There are multiple ways of fixing it:

- Don't use an executor, just start a thread, which will end when the `run()` method of `StreamGobbler` ends.

  ```java
  StreamGobbler streamGobbler = ...
  new Thread(streamGobbler).start();
  int exitCode = process.waitFor();
  ```
- Shut down the executor when you're done with it.

  ```java
  StreamGobbler streamGobbler = ...
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  executor.submit(streamGobbler);
  int exitCode = process.waitFor();
  executor.shutdown();
  ```

Comment: But it’s worth noting that if all the thread is supposed to do, is to print the output of the subprocess to the standard output, the preferred way is to use `ProcessBuilder` and [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) to let the subprocess write to the right target in the first place, without the need to copy the output manually. Then, there is no need for an extra thread.